# why this code runs slow on device but fast on simulator in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Any thoughts on why this code runs slow on device but fast on simulator in iphone, I am making a game in cocos2d, and I am moving an object from one place to another , throught CCTouchBegan , CCTouchMoved, CCTouchEneded (ccp function) and after that I take the action on it,

can any buddy tell me what is the main issue to solve this problem,

Comment: Please review your previous questions and accept answers when applicable. From Stack Overflow’s FAQ: ‘When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)’

Answer (score 6):

The simulator is a *simulator* not an *emulator*. All the simulator really does is provide a window for running an iOS app. You'll notice that when you build for the simulator, the system architecture is set to i386. You're compiling for the Mac when you use the simulator. There's no memory restrictions, sandboxing etc. In fact, I think your app even shows up as it's own process.

That's why when you run it on the device, you get hammered. You just have to work on optimizing your code. The simulator is terrible. Just use your device for debugging, it'll save you the confusion. If you post your code, we might be able to help you speed it up.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

The basic hardware of the computer on which the Simulator runs and that of an iOS device are very different, from CPU clock speed, to instruction parallelism, to branch prediction, to cache size, to memory bandwidth, to memory available.  The possible compiler optimizations might also be different, given the different ISAs.  It's not uncommon for general code to run an order of magnitude faster on the Simulator on a Mac than on an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons like (also) #simulator vs actual device

1. Low Memory can be the first problem as in your actual device as you will install different kinds of huge applications but in case of simulator you will not install t.
2. Low power problem as the actual device will be powered by battery and not like simulators which get constant power all the time.
3. Other application interfering with your application run cycle but in simulator you will hardly run any application while you are testing your application.
4. You cannot see the UserInterface(UI) as clear in your MAC as you can see in your actual device, so which appears correct may not be actually correct.
5. Application interfered by calls, in simulator this type of interference will never happen.